# How do I display the nth result of an ls command?

Tags: text-processing, ls

I used this command to display the first result of files in my directory.

```
  ls | head -n 1
```

My simple question is, how can I modify this command to display say the nth result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use sed to select a single line, for example line 12:

```
ls | sed -n 12p
```

Option `-n` asks sed not to print every line (which is what it normally does), and `12p` asks to print the pattern space when the address is 12.

Answer (score 11):

Straight forward with `awk`:

```
$ ls / | awk 'NR==4'
etc
```

Comment: Arguably more clear than `sed` because `NR` presumably stands for "number (of) record", and the equality operator makes sense. Not clear what `p` means without having to look it up,  nor `-n`, so harder to remember.

Comment: @ijoseph To me, it is super obvious that `p` is print. If you ever use `sed` with `-n`, you need it. NR could mean anything. "Record"?

Comment: @rjmunro ah yes, here's the argument :). (Fair enough). (Honestly, by me engaging in this argument, maybe the emotional salience will mean that I'll remember *either* of these methods)

Answer (score 10):

There may be better ways to do this, but this is probably the easiest: `ls | head -<n> | tail -1`

Answer (score 4):

I have this in my `.bashrc`.

```
lsn () {
    ls ${@:2} | head -n $1 | tail -n 1
}
```

This is called as such: `lsn 4` for example. The `$2` allows you to use
options on `ls` so `lsn 4 -lah` is also valid.

Note: when using the `-l` flag on `ls` there is an additional line at the top of the result. Which would skew this function's result.

Comment: It would be more general to do `ls "$@"` to pass `lsn`'s arguments down to `ls`. Of course, after using `shift` to take out `$1`.

Comment: I have updated my answer using the `$@` approach. Well spotted.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` and glob qualifiers:

```
ls -d -- *([7])
```

or

```
print -rl -- *([7])
```

will print the 7th file from the list of files sorted by name.

```
ls -d -- *(om[7])
```

or

```
print -rl -- *(om[7])
```

will print the 7th file from the list of files s`o`rted by `m`time (newest first - similar to extracting the 7th entry from `ls -t` output).

---

Ideally, if you're processing `ls` output, you should use something like `ls -q | command(s)` where `-q` prints `?` instead of funky chars (like newlines) and `command(s)` processes only *N* lines of output, prints the *Nth* and then stops.

Answer (score 1):

With tail and head (added nl for clarity). Let's fetch the fifth line :

```
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC ~ $ ls | nl
     1  total 8.3M
     2  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  20K Jul  8 15:53 2.docx
     3  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  20K Jul  8 15:53 3.docx
     4  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul  7 10:11 AUDIO
     5  drwxr-xr-x  3 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K May 28 09:33 BACKUPS
     6  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K May 17 13:49 BZR
     7  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 15 17:10 CODE
     8  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K May 25 10:24 Desktop
     9  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  34K Dec  2  2014 dget_problem.ods
    10  drwxr-xr-x 12 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul  7 10:00 DOCUMENTS
    11  drwx------  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Apr  6 11:39 Downloads
    12  drwxr-xr-x 16 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul 12 11:06 DOWNLOADS
    13  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 22 15:38 IMAGES
    14  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  690 Jan 25 14:25 IT_Alias.vcf
    15  drwxr-xr-x  4 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Dec  2  2014 MACONF
    16  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche 6.2M May 12 10:44 mtr.ogv
    17  drwxr-xr-x  4 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jan  5  2015 MUSIQUE
    18  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar  2 16:29 NOTES
    19  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche 2.0M May 12 10:42 out.ogv
    20  -rw-r--r--  3 ychaouche ychaouche  62K Apr  2  2014 php-mode.el
    21  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Apr  8 13:25 Pictures
    22  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jan  6  2015 Projects
    23  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  353 Jan 12  2015 proxylog.dat
    24  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar 19 15:35 public_html
    25  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche   21 Nov 23  2014 registrationcode
    26  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 21 10:55 REPOS
    27  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul 20 10:56 SCRIPTS
    28  drwxr-xr-x  8 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 11 10:36 SRV
    29  drwxr-xr-x 14 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 30 16:26 TMP
    30  drwxr-xr-x  5 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 28 16:56 VIDEOS
    31  drwxr-xr-x  7 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar 18 11:35 VirtualBox VMs
    32  drwxr-xr-x  3 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jan 22 14:28 VIRTUALENVS
    33  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul  7 12:24 WTMP
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC ~ $
```

This will jump to the fifth line :

```
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC ~ $ ls | nl | tail -n +5
     5  drwxr-xr-x  3 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K May 28 09:33 BACKUPS
     6  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K May 17 13:49 BZR
     7  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 15 17:10 CODE
     8  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K May 25 10:24 Desktop
     9  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  34K Dec  2  2014 dget_problem.ods
    10  drwxr-xr-x 12 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul  7 10:00 DOCUMENTS
    11  drwx------  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Apr  6 11:39 Downloads
    12  drwxr-xr-x 16 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul 12 11:06 DOWNLOADS
    13  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 22 15:38 IMAGES
    14  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  690 Jan 25 14:25 IT_Alias.vcf
    15  drwxr-xr-x  4 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Dec  2  2014 MACONF
    16  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche 6.2M May 12 10:44 mtr.ogv
    17  drwxr-xr-x  4 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jan  5  2015 MUSIQUE
    18  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar  2 16:29 NOTES
    19  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche 2.0M May 12 10:42 out.ogv
    20  -rw-r--r--  3 ychaouche ychaouche  62K Apr  2  2014 php-mode.el
    21  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Apr  8 13:25 Pictures
    22  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jan  6  2015 Projects
    23  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche  353 Jan 12  2015 proxylog.dat
    24  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar 19 15:35 public_html
    25  -rw-r--r--  1 ychaouche ychaouche   21 Nov 23  2014 registrationcode
    26  drwxr-xr-x  6 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 21 10:55 REPOS
    27  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul 20 10:56 SCRIPTS
    28  drwxr-xr-x  8 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 11 10:36 SRV
    29  drwxr-xr-x 14 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 30 16:26 TMP
    30  drwxr-xr-x  5 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jun 28 16:56 VIDEOS
    31  drwxr-xr-x  7 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar 18 11:35 VirtualBox VMs
    32  drwxr-xr-x  3 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jan 22 14:28 VIRTUALENVS
    33  drwxr-xr-x  2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Jul  7 12:24 WTMP
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC ~ $
```

Then, obviously head -1

```
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC ~ $ ls | nl | tail -n +5 | head -1
     5  drwxr-xr-x  3 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K May 28 09:33 BACKUPS
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC ~ $
```