# Printing every Nth line out of a large file into a new file

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to print every Nth line out of a file with more than 300,000 records into a  new file. This has to happen every Nth record until it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214445/117549

Comment: Looking in your comments, we cant understand what you need. Provide sample input and sample output. Do you need a range ? From Nth line up to EOF?

Comment: thanks, I have 355,000 records which is sorted but I need to get a sample of the data (1/3 which is about 100,000) so I thought if I retrieve the 300th of the sorted file from 1 to EOF, I should be able to get a fair sample.

Comment: What the word "records" means to you? Do you refer to number of lines in a file or you refer to a number of files? Better describe your problem with terms like files and lines. Avoid the word record. Tell us how many lines has your file or how many files you need to parse.

Comment: Please explain your requirements more clearly. Against my answer you wrote. "For example for an input file with 300000 I should get 100000 records in the output." That sentence doesn't make any sense, unless if you mentioned that n=3 and you wanted the 3rd, 6th, 9th line. Or perhaps, you wanted the 1st, 4th, 7th line. There are multiple different solutions because the way you're asking the question is not clear.

Answer (score 108):

```
awk 'NR % 5 == 0' input > output
```

This prints every fifth line.

To use an environment variable:

```
NUM=5
awk -v NUM=$NUM 'NR % NUM == 0' input > output
```

Comment: I ran this command and got only 1166 in the output. I expected 100,000.

Comment: awk 'NR % 300 ==0' 350000.records > 100000-records

Comment: If you want 1/3 the file, you wanted every **3rd** line, not 300th.

Comment: `awk 'NR % 3 == 0' 350000.records > 100000-records`. That will give you `$((350000/3))` lines, or 116666.

Comment: That is correct, an idiotic mistake. Thanks very much

Comment: As commented in your "answer" below, pleas accept this answer as the solution. Thank you.

Comment: or every 5th line starting at the 1st using `NR % 5 == 1` 
or every 5th line starting at the 4th using `NR % 5 == 4`

Comment: ffmpeg and other programs expect the data of a file or files piped in.  Your solution helped me list all the JPGs in a dir and feed ever 5th filename to cat to read the data to pipe to ffmpeg.  Couldn't have done it without you! (I looked all over and tried dozens of possible solutions).

@northern-bradley your `==1` helps too if there's only 1 file in the directory.

`cat $(ls *.jpg | awk 'NR % 5 == 1' -) | ffmpeg -r 15 -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -r 30 test.mp4`

Answer (score 52):

To print every *N*  th line, use

```
sed -n '0~Np'
```

For example, to copy every 5th line of `oldfile` to `newfile`, do

```
sed -n '0~5p' oldfile > newfile
```

This uses `sed`’s *first* **~***step* address form,
which means “match every *step*’th line starting
with line *first*.” 
In theory,
this would print lines 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, …, up to the end of the file. 
Of course there is no line 0, so it just prints lines 5, 10, 20, 25, …; 
`0~5` is just a convenient alternative way of saying `5~5`
(which prints every 5th line starting with line 5;
i.e., lines 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, …).

For another example of this `sed` capability
(which does not answer the question),

```
sed -n '2~5p' oldfile
```

would print lines 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, …, up to the end of the file.

Note: This approach requires GNU sed,
as the *first* **~***step* address form
is a non-portable extension. 
(Some old versions of GNU sed may require the `5~5` form
as opposed to the `0~5` form.)

Comment: i like that this uses `sed` which is what i originally searched for but to my brain @deathgrip's use of `awk` is clearer

Comment: The `sed` solution is about 3 times faster to run than the `awk` solution on my computer. I confirm it is not a [standard option](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) though.

Comment: just a note that the `~` syntax requires [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: Just a note that the answer *already **says*** that the ``~`` syntax requires GNU sed,  and has done so since March 5, 2021 (long before you posted that comment).

Comment: Outstanding answer. I appreciate the '2~5p' addendum because I wanted to split a file into 5 parts, and I could do "every 5th line" 5 times to create them. Using a different first number each time, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the perl version:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. % 5 == 0;' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Yay to the succinct Perl one-liner in the 2020's! Take that, Python!!!

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to sed, we have also awk:

```
$ seq 1000000000 |awk 'NR==500000{print;exit}'
500000
```

NR=Number of line you want to print (and then exit to avoid waiting the file to finish).
In your case

```
awk 'NR==Nth{print;exit}' inputfile >outputfile
```

Where Nth is the Nth line number you need to print.

Comment: Looks like the question was initially worded badly, and this answers the wrong question.