# Retrieve Nth records from a file until end of file is reached

Tags: text-processing

How can I retrieve the Nth record of a large text file and insert them into a new file?

Comment: How do you define "record"? What does some sample data look like? What have you tried? https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You've just duplicated https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369181/117549 -- be more specific about what you want

Comment: It sounded like, from the other question, that you want every N lines

Comment: create a small example that could represent your problem. give sample input  / sample output.

Comment: That is right, I put the new question out there before I noticed your tip. The records are 20 digit numbers, the total is more than 300,000. The first 4 digits are representative of location and year (e.g. 0117). I need one third of them to reflect the weigh of each category (location-year). I thought I get a fair sample if I sort the data and take the 300th record written in a new file.

Comment: 0100000044116R007010
0105000045035C005005

Comment: This is location 01 and year 2000

Comment: Edit the question to include these details

Comment: Thrig, the "duplicate" I linked to was originally a different question, as evidenced by the answers. In that Q's comments, it came to light that the OP wanted something different, and so opened this question.

Comment: @JeffSchaller regardless, the "duplicate" has been edited so it's now the same question... I'm voting to close anyway since they are now the same. what are we going to do, revert the edits to the other question so the answers make sense? then we're back to square one with a question that would be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NUM=5
awk -v NUM=$NUM 'NR % NUM == 0' input > output
```

Set environment variable NUM to the desired number.
"input" the name of your input file.
"output" the name of your output file will contain every NUMth line from the input.