# remove most but not all lines containing carriage return (\r)

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, pipe

I have a process which outputs too many status-lines with carriage return (\r). I can filter all those status lines by piping them through

```
sed '/\r/d'
```

I would instead like to filter all of these lines except, e.g. every 3.
Is this possible with standard Unix-Tools (awk?) or do I need a script for that? Lines without CR should be left untouched.

Given Output:

```
$ (printf '%s\n' {1..10};   printf  '%s\r\n' {1..10}; printf '%s\n' {1..10};)  | cat -v
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1^M
2^M
3^M
4^M
5^M
6^M
7^M
8^M
9^M
10^M
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Wanted output (or any other pattern):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1^M
4^M
7^M
10^M
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Do these lines have CR+LF and you only want to remove the CR or are the lines only CR-separated (classic MacOS style) and you want to remove most of those CRs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing every Nth line out of a large file into a new file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369181/printing-every-nth-line-out-of-a-large-file-into-a-new-file)

Comment: I clarified my question. Lines without CR should be left untouched.

Comment: Personally, I think the correct is to fix the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '!(/\r$/ && ((++c)%3 != 1))' file | cat -v
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1^M
4^M
7^M
10^M
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

---

Original answer:

Sounds like all you need is this, using any awk:

```
awk -v RS='\r' '{ORS=(NR%10000 ? "" : RS)} 1'
```

e.g. using this as input:

```
$ printf '%s\r\n' {1..10} | cat -v
1^M
2^M
3^M
4^M
5^M
6^M
7^M
8^M
9^M
10^M
```

Removing all but every 3rd `\r`:

```
$ printf '%s\r\n' {1..10} | awk -v RS='\r' '{ORS=(NR%3 ? "" : RS)} 1' | cat -v
1
2
3^M
4
5
6^M
7
8
9^M
10
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, my question wasn't very clear. I want to get rid of the lines completely, not just the \r. I've edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU sed`, we use the hold space for counting.

```bash
sed -E '
  /\r$/{
    G;/\n$/P
    s/.*\n/./
    /.{3}/z;x;d
  }
' file
```

---

Using `awk`, we Use the variable c as a circular counter that gets reset whenver it reaches 3.

```bash
awk '
!/\r$/ || !c++
c==3{c=0}
' file
```

---

Assuming the carriage returns (`\r`) , whenever they occur, occur at the end of a line feed (`\n`) delimited record.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fringe way to do it in awk :

```
{m,g}awk '((+$_ % 3) % NF)~(!_<NF)' FS='\r$'  # yes that's a 
                                              # tilde ~ not a minus -

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1^M
4^M
7^M
10^M
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Other ways of saying the same thing

```
mawk 'NF-!_== (+$+_   %    3    ) % NF' FS='\r$'
gawk 'NF-!_== ( $(_++)%(_+_+_--)) % NF' FS='\r$'
```